Product Visibility on Lead Line Item when Price Book 'No Access'
Working on a feature where users can only see the products related to their price book use and manual sharing.
This works for things such as opportunity line items where the price book is selected and the products in the book are shown.  In that instance, they can only select their shared price book, which then only shows products related.
However, when using this functionality on a lead, and trying to add a lead line item to the lead, the user can still see all products regardless of price book when selecting from the product dropdown.
Are there any solutions or insight to get around this?
